# How to avoid omissions in video information acquisition when using the YouTube Data API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

**Assumption / What I want to achieve**

I want to use YouTube Data API V3 to get the video ID without any omissions, and find out if the cause of the trouble is in the code or in the video settings of YouTube (API side).

**Problem**

The following code is used to get the video information from YouTube Data API, but the number of IDs I got did not match the number of videos that are actually posted.

```python
from apiclient.discovery 
import build
id = "UCD-miitqNY3nyukJ4Fnf4_A" #sampleID

token_check = None
nextPageToken = None
id_info = []

while True:
    if token_check != None:
        nextPageToken = token_check

    Search_Video = youtube.search().list(
        part = "id",
        channelId = id,
        maxResults = 50,
        order = 'date',
        safeSearch = "none",
        pageToken = nextPageToken
    ).execute()

    for ID_check in Search_Video.get("items", []):
        if ID_check["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
            id_info.append(ID_check["id"]["videoId"])

    try:
        token_check = Search_Video["nextPageToken"]
    except:
        print(len(id_info)) #check number of IDs
        break
```

I also used the YouTube Data API function to get the `videoCount` information of the channel, and noticed that the value of `videoCount` did not match the number of IDs obtained by the code above, which is why I posted this.

According to `channels()` API, this channel have 440 videos, but the above code gets only 412 videos (at 10:30 a.m. JST).

**Supplemental Information**

・Python 3.9.0

・YouTube Data API v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to acknowledge that the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint *does not have a crisp behavior*. That means you *should not expect precise results* from it. Google does not document this behavior as such, but this forum has many posts from users experiencing that.

If you want to obtain all the IDs of videos uploaded by a  given channel then you should employ the following two-step procedure:

**Step 1: Obtain the ID of the Uploads Playlist of a Channel.**

Invoke the [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) API endpoint, queried with its request parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#id) set to the ID of the channel of your interest (or, otherwise, with its request parameter [`mine`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#mine) set to `true`) for to obtain that channel's uploads playlist ID, [`contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads).

```py
def get_channel_uploads_playlist_id(youtube, channel_id):
    response = youtube.channels().list(
        fields = 'items/contentDetails/relatedPlaylists/uploads',
        part = 'contentDetails',
        id = channel_id,
        maxResults = 1
    ).execute()

    items = response.get('items')
    if items:
        return items[0] \
            ['contentDetails'] \
            ['relatedPlaylists'] \
            .get('uploads')
    else:
        return None
```

Do note that the function `get_channel_uploads_playlist_id` *should only be called once* for to obtain the uploads playlist
ID of a given channel; subsequently use that ID as many times as needed.

**Step 2: Retrieve All IDs of Videos of a Playlist.**

Invoke the [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) API endpoint, queried with its request parameter [`playlistId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#playlistId) set to the ID obtained from `get_channel_uploads_playlist_id`:

```py
def get_playlist_video_ids(youtube, playlist_id):
    request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
        fields = 'nextPageToken,items/snippet/resourceId',
        playlistId = playlist_id,
        part = 'snippet',
        maxResults = 50
    )
    videos = []

    is_video = lambda item: \
        item['snippet']['resourceId']['kind'] == 'youtube#video'
    video_id = lambda item: \
        item['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']

    while request:
        response = request.execute()

        items = response.get('items', [])
        assert len(items) <= 50

        videos.extend(map(video_id, filter(is_video, items)))

        request = youtube.playlistItems().list_next(
            request, response)

    return videos
```

Do note that, when using the [Google's APIs Client Library for Python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) (as you do), [API result set pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination) is trivially simple: just use the `list_next` method of the Python API object corresponding to the respective paginated API endpoint (as was shown above):

```py
request = API_OBJECT.list(...)

while request:
    response = request.execute()
    ...
    request = API_OBJECT.list_next(
        request, response)
```

Also note that above I used twice the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) request parameter. This is good practice: ask from the API only the info that is of actual use.

Yet an important note: the `PlaylistItems.list` endpoint would not return items that correspond to *private* videos of a channel when invoked with an API key. This happens when your `youtube` object was constructed by calling the function `apiclient.discovery.build` upon passing to it the parameter `developerKey`.

`PlaylistItems.list` returns items corresponding to private videos only to the channel owner. This happens when the `youtube` object is constructed by calling the function `apiclient.discovery.build` upon passing to it the parameter `credentials` and if `credentials` refer to the channel that owns the respective playlist.

An additional important note: according to [Google staff](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166292064#comment2), there's an upper 20000 limit set *by design* for the number of items returned via `PlaylistItems.list` endpoint when queried for a given channel's uploads playlist. This is unfortunate, but a fact.